# extracting data from query in elasticsearch in yii2

Tags: elasticsearch, yii2

When I did a match query like this:

```
$result = Customer::find()->query(["match" => ["name" => "george"]])->all();
```

When I serialize the `$result : echo serialize($result);`,
I am getting the result below. So how can I extract the name information from it.

```
a:1:{i:0;O:24:"frontend\models\Customer":12:{s:35:"yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord_id";s:2:"18";s:38:"yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord_score";d:1.058217;s:40:"yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord_version";N;s:42:"yii\elasticsearch\ActiveRecord_highlight";N;s:36:"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord_attributes";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:12:"peter george";s:7:"address";s:6:"langer";}s:39:"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord_oldAttributes";a:2:{s:4:"name";s:12:"peter george";s:7:"address";s:6:"langer";}s:33:"yii\db\BaseActiveRecord_related";a:0:{}s:23:"yii\base\Model_errors";N;s:27:"yii\base\Model_validators";N;s:25:"yii\base\Model_scenario";s:7:"default";s:27:"yii\base\Component_events";a:0:{}s:30:"yii\base\Component_behaviors";a:0:{}}}
```

Comment: Why do you call `serialize` in the first place? The call to `all()` will get you an array of customers whose name matches `george`, so you can simply iterate over it and retrieve the name of each record.

Comment: I have a similar problem, when I call 'die()' the script just stops. Still struggling with it.

Answer (score 0):

By default any query via an `ActiveRecord`-derived class will return a set of models of that same class as result.

So you can either use

```
foreach ($result as $customer) {
    echo $customer->name . ', ' $customer->address;
}
```

Or you can tell the query that you simply want an array:

```
$result = Customer::find()->query(["match" => ["name" => "george"]])->asArray()->all();
foreach ($result as $customer) {
    echo $customer['name'] . ', ' $customer['address'];
}
```

FYI: technically the `ActiveRecord` also provides `ArrayAccess`-behavior, so `$customer['name']` should also work in scenario 1 should you prefer that notation.